# How do I use the rubber strap with my drill's chuck key?

Tags: repair, drill

The instructions are rather obtuse on the matter, so what do I do with this rubber strap that, I believe, is intended to keep the chuck key with my drill?

How do I apply it?

Is the slot at the bottom of the drill handle (see image) involved?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rubber / stretchy plastic strap looks like the following when it is installed around the drill cord and attached to the chuck key.

[image]

A couple of quick pointers:

1. Pull the two holes end through the slotted end first to make the loop around the drill cord.
2. When installing the chuck key insert the longer arm of the key first into its hole and finish with the shorter arm.

Comment: Quick tip: secure the strap near the plug. This will encourage the good practice of unplugging before changing bits. (Though this is very much a "do as we say, not as we do" item, I'm afraid.)

Answer (score 3):

The end on the right slips through the end on the left, making a loop around the drill cord.

The right end fits over the smaller diameter cross bar arm of your chuck key. (You may have to slide the arm out, insert it into one tab, slide it through the chuck key body, then slip over the other tab of the retainer.

Comment: I sort of understand your description.  Does it hook at all into the slot on the bottom of the drill handle?  Can you provide a photo or image of what the result should look like?

Comment: No, the slot isn't involved. Here's a link direct from delta/dewalt- http://www.deltamachinery.com/faq/102-how-do-i-attachthe-chuck-key-to-the-chuck-key-holder  You wouldn't want it attached to the slot anyway- it would never be able to reach the chuck. You want it at least a foot down the cord, so that you can bring it up to the chuck.